# remove from the string "89dde7.rqsnhq34h.fmu8s1vn0i94hl.tgz.tar.gz" only the ".tar.gz"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

remove from the string `89dde7.rqsnhq34h.fmu8s1vn0i94hl.tgz.tar.gz` only the `.tar.gz` part and the result should be `89dde7.rqsnhq34h.fmu8s1vn0i94hl.tgz`.
It can also happen some files with this extension:
`91xhq8vkxlkdfpmfg566qahrwkh01c7n0scpdsr4p4vf6.tbz.tar.bz2` and others with double extension tar.tbz tar.zip and so on ...

In case .tar.zip the result must be `nomearchivio.tar` in the case `91xhq8vkxlkdfpmfg566qahrwkh01c7n0scpdsr4p4vf6.tbz.tar.bz2` must be `91xhq8vkxlkdfpmfg566qahrwkh01c7n0scpdsr4p4vf6.tbz`

I use this :

```
nameFile= "89dde7.rqsnhq34h.fmu8s1vn0i94hl.tgz.tar.gz"
name=${nameFile%.*}
```

and the result is :

```
echo $name
89dde7.rqsnhq34h.fmu8s1vn0i94hl.tgz.tar
```

can you help me? Thanks

P.S. note that there are also other points within the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know exactly what you want to remove, just write it in full:

```
name=${nameFile%.tar.gz}
```

Or to remove the last two "extensions" `.*.*`:

```
name=${nameFile%.*.*}
```

Comment: I can not give this indication because I have other files with different extensions such as:
- 91xhq8vkxlkdfpmfg566qahrwkh01c7n0scpdsr4p4vf6.tbz.tar.bz2
- m3mcsm8q1g.tgz
.
.
.

Comment: So what is the general rule? Please update your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sed` and remove the last 7 characters

`echo $nameFile |sed 's/.\{7\}$//'`

Comment: I have to assign your command within the variable name because in case I find other files with extension of the type:
"91xhq8vkxlkdfpmfg566qahrwkh01c7n0scpdsr4p4vf6.tbz.tar.bz2" so I'll have to check. I can do to assign your command to the variable name
name = $ {nameFile | sed 's /. \ {7 \} $ //'} ??

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try to `awk`, for example:

```
echo 89dde7.rqsnhq34h.fmu8s1vn0i94hl.tgz.tar.gz | awk -F '\.tgz' '{print $1".tgz"}'
```

It will output:

```
89dde7.rqsnhq34h.fmu8s1vn0i94hl.tgz
```

For other files:

```
echo "01c7n0scpdsr4p4vf6.tbz.tar.bz2" |  awk -F '\.tbz' '{print $1".tbz"}'
```

It will output:

```
01c7n0scpdsr4p4vf6.tbz
```

In this case, `awk` is using as a delimiter `-F '\.tbz'` your pattern, `.tgz` or `tbz` and then prints all items found at the left + your desired extension.